# What is Python symmetric_difference and how is it different from XOR operation?

Tags: python, set, xor, symmetric-difference

While learning Python from http://www.learnpython.org/en/Sets I encountered the notion of symmetric_difference between sets.
I thought it gave the same output as 'exclusive or' operations on sets.
How is it different?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. XORing sets works by calling the `symmetric_difference` function. This is from the implementation of sets in sets.py:

```
def __xor__(self, other):
    """Return the symmetric difference of two sets as a new set.

    (I.e. all elements that are in exactly one of the sets.)
    """
    if not isinstance(other, BaseSet):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.symmetric_difference(other)

def symmetric_difference(self, other):
    """Return the symmetric difference of two sets as a new set.

    (I.e. all elements that are in exactly one of the sets.)
    """
    result = self.__class__()
    data = result._data
    value = True
    selfdata = self._data
    try:
        otherdata = other._data
    except AttributeError:
        otherdata = Set(other)._data
    for elt in ifilterfalse(otherdata.__contains__, selfdata):
        data[elt] = value
    for elt in ifilterfalse(selfdata.__contains__, otherdata):
        data[elt] = value
    return result
```

As you can see the XOR implementation makes sure that you are indeed working on sets only, but otherwise there are no differences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is pretty much the same, just XOR is an operation on booleans, and `symmetric_difference` is an operation on sets. Actually, even your linked documentation page says this:

> To find out which members attended **only one** of the events, use the "symmetric_difference" method

You can also see [this more detailed mathematical explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84184/relation-between-xor-and-symmetric-difference) about relationship between logical XOR and symmetric difference on sets.

Comment: Well, they're not _exactly_ the same thing, they're isomorphic operations (as discussed in the accepted answer at your link), but it makes perfect sense for Python to overload the `^` exclusive_OR operator to call the `symmetric_difference` method when it's applied to a pair of sets.

Comment: I clarified this a bit.